# An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated '__NSDictionaryI' object (zombie) at address 0x1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, multipeer-connectivity

I have an app using Multipeer Connectivity to send a string from one iOS device to another iOS device. It works and doesn't work.

The app is pretty much the app seen on the tutorial of this link: http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/

Sometimes, the app will send about 30 messages and then crashes, other times, it will crash on the 1st or 2nd message.

Xcode is giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS for the crash.

I used NSZombie to give some assistance, and it has provided me with the below, but I am fairly new and unable to understand the reason behind the crashes.

[image: ScreenShot of NSZombie]

I'f the crash is due to the NSDictionary's, there are only 2 in my application:

```
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"peerID": peerID,
                           @"state" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:state]
                           };

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCDidChangeStateNotification"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:dict];
}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"data": data,
                           @"peerID": peerID
                           };

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCDidReceiveDataNotification"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:dict];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You somewhere have a pointer to an object that isn't.  It no doubt used to be but then it got "collected", because the problem pointer was not "strong" (or a handful of similar only more confusing scenarios).

Comment: To find out where this is occurring, learn how to obtain and interpret the "exception stack trace".

Comment: FWIW that tutorial you have linked to is pretty poor and you should probably look elsewhere for a good MPC example. If I find one I will post one.

Answer (score -1):

Zombies generally come when you try to access any deallocated object.

If you are using ARC, then you don't need to worry much about Zombies, X code does it for you but there are some cases in which zombies come in ARC project also. I never had this kind of issue.

If you are using Non ARC project, then you need to deallocate the objects manually.

As your error message suggests, you have used a dictionary's object that is not allocated or deallocated already and you are trying to use it again.

If you want to see where the zombie is, then please click on the arrow that is shown after the message in alert. You will be redirected to the line which caused your Zombie.

Please update your code according to that.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when clicking on the next arrow, it shows "Unknown" and then the next arrow shows "Terminated" ?

Comment: If you're using ARC you definitely **do** need to worry about zombies.

Comment: @HotLicks: As far as I have worked till now, zombies have never come in my project of ARC. I might be wrong so can you please correct? Thanks...

Comment: @Manesh: Please alloc and init your dictionary object where you are using it.

Comment: Zombies are perhaps less likely using ARC, but when they occur (which they do) they're probably much harder to trace down.  I haven't had one yet, so can't tell you the circumstances that generate them, but there have been a number of reports of zombies in ARC apps here.

Comment: Please make it ARC compatible and then check this crash occurs or not. I think you will be good to go after that.